# symfony form_widget add/ change attributes

Tags: forms, symfony, button

I have a symfony form_wiget with a pre-defined label, if i do:

`{{ form_widget(form.button, {'label': 'label' }) }}`

the label changes, but if i do:

```
 {{ form_widget(form.button, { 'attr': {'label': ' ', 'title': 'title'}
 }) }}
```

I get a `label = ' '` in source code but the actual label text does not change. anyone has any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. turns out label is not an attribute.

```
{{ form_widget(form.button, { 'label': 'label' , 'attr': {'title': 'title'} }) }}
```

works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do not show the label set label to `false`.

`{{ form_widget(form.button, { 'label': false }) }}`